# Подсчет уникальных кликов по ссылке

Tags: php, база-данных, сессия

Здравствуйте!

Реализую подсчет уникальных кликов по ссылке.

Вид ссылки:

```
http://test.loc/product/3/ticket=4thd45fsvnfg7
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['ticket'])){
   $ticket = mysqli_escape_string($connection, strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['ticket']))));
   if(!isset($_SESSION['ticket'])){
      count_ticket();
   }      
   $_SESSION['ticket'] = $ticket;
}
```

Функция count_ticket:

```
function count_ticket(){
  global $connection;
  $query = "SELECT `count` FROM `ds_customers_ticket` WHERE `ticket` = '{$_SESSION['ticket']}'";
  $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query)  or die(mysqli_error());  
  if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
    $query = ("UPDATE `ds_customers_ticket` SET `count` = `count` + 1 WHERE `ticket` = '{$_SESSION['ticket']}'");
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
  }
}
```

Если существует `$_GET['ticket']` создается сессия, но перед ее созданием я вызываю функцию `count_ticket()`. По умолчанию в базе данных значение количества переходов по ссылке = 0.

Необходимо подсчитывать уникальные переходы, т.е., если сессия существует уже, засчитывать переход по ссылке не нужно (это в случае, если пользователь будет нажимать F5).
У меня, к сожалению, не засчитывает кол-во перехода, если пользователь открыл страницу первый раз и последующие его обновления страницы.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

С условием:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['ticket'])){
      count_ticket();
}
```

Отлично все считает, но засчитывает каждое обновление страницы.

Comment: Можно, конечно, с помощью setcookie решить. `if(!isset($_COOKIE[ticket])){count_ticket();}` затем ниже строчкой `setcookie("ticket", $ticket);` Что скажете?

Comment: Так сработает потому что cookie положены на компьютер пользователя, но серверу ещё не отправлены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, что нужно было поправить:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['ticket'])){
   count_ticket($ticket);
}elseif($_SESSION['ticket'] != $ticket){
   count_ticket($ticket);
}
```

И соответственно принимать `$ticket` в функции `function count_ticket($ticket){...}`

`elseif` необходим на случай, если этот же пользователь перейдет по ссылке уже с другим тикетом. Если убрать условие, то сессия уже существует у этого пользователя и клик по новому тикету у этого же пользователя не засчитается!

Пользуйтесь на здоровье:)

Answer (score 0):

а) использовать `distinct` при выборке из БД

б) делать выборку по тикету и анализировать последнее время записи (или просто игнорировать при наличии в БД такого тикета)

Comment: покажите пример, пожалуйста. О distinct слышу первый раз. Тикет будет всегда в БД, так как он прикреплен к пользователю.

Comment: Какой смысл анализировать в БД последнее время записи или игнорировать? Нужно понимать, что нельзя накручивать клики одному и тому же пользователю. Это можно сделать по ip-адресу, например, а я решил по сессии. А в Вашем случае это не учесть.